# BIND DNS-server not starting

Tags: bind, ubuntu-14.04, plesk

I've got a VPS running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and Plesk 12.5.30*. I'm trying to setup a master DNS server using the BIND component for Plesk.

The problem is that the service doesn't start and there is no error message. When I start BIND using Plesk, I get this message:

[image: message in plesk]

But nothing happens. And when I start BIND via command line using `service bind9 start`, nothing happens. No output, no error and the service is still not active.

All the possible solutions, I've found, were related to AppArmor, but that is not installed. (I could install Ubuntu+Plesk as "package" via my provider, so AppArmor was removed by default)

Does anyone has an idea, why I can't start BIND?

---

<sub>*I know, that questions about Plesk are often off-topic, but I also accept solutions that are done via command line and not via Plesk.</sub>

Comment: What's in the logs?

Comment: @MadHatter In which logs exactly? Where do I have to search?

Comment: And now you know why we don't like control-panel based questions.  I can't tell you where ubuntu syslogs daemon-related output; I could tell you where to look on CentOS, but you need to know your own system.  You could start with `grep named /var/log/syslog`, see if that unearths anything useful.

Comment: @MadHatter Checked the syslog file both with your command and manually: No output related to bind and actually no output at all around the time when I executed `service bind9 start`

Comment: Might want to have a look in `/etc/init.d/bind9` and see what things might cause the script not to get as far as starting the daemon.  What's the exit status of the start (`service bind9 start ; echo $?`)?

Comment: @MadHatter This file is almost empty. It just contains `#!/bin/sh` and `exit 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55540/discussion-between-felixsfd-and-madhatter).

Comment: Oh.  Well, that's not going to start the daemon.  Now you know *another* reason why we don't do control-panel quesetions - many of these dreadful things modify their systems so they can't be admin'ed any other way, and it looks like this might be such a case.  I know you're open to a non-plesk solution, but it looks like your system isn't.  Sorry, I'm voting to close.

Comment: Thanks! You pointed me to the right direction. I've found a Gist, with a config file to use: https://gist.github.com/mattrude/449c31d93b1544735a52 BIND seems to start now

Comment: OK, it'd be good to get the question put to bed, and better to do it with an actual answer.  **All credit to you** for taking a pointer, digging and solving your own problem - that way lies wisdom and knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the plesk-based system had a null `/etc/init.d/bind9` file.  Once you put a real startup file in place, you were able to start the daemon from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps bad syntax in a configuration file?  I've seen issues after patching BIND, that it complains about syntax, or characters used in the logs and doesn't start.